# How to set the output of robot(subprocess) of shell to be as environment variable in bash

Tags: bash, shell, robotframework

I have a robotframework test which I am producing the output in the below format. I intentionally tried `export` so I can set them as bash environment variable to be used later.

How do I achieve this?

Command:

```
robot -d output cli.robot | grep -i -e "id1" -e "id2"
```

here

VAR1=id1
VAR2=id2

Output out of that is :

```
export VAR1=cfdsgbds4r4ew43vf
export VAR2=34-sdggs4fsz9vrfg
```

these values of id1 and id2 are the ones that are being assigned to VAR1 and VAR2.

My Goal is to be able to do just that. I don't want that output above to be saved to any file

```
echo $VAR1
echo $VAR2
```

Comment: `grep -i -e "id1"` there's no `id1` in the output, are you sure that `grep` is correct?

Comment: id1 is `cfdsgbds4r4ew43vf` and id2 is `34-sdggs4fsz9vrfg` value. Yes grep is 100% correct. Edited the question now.

Comment: Don't you want `grep -e VAR1 -e VAR2`? There is no `id1` nor `id2` strings in the output!. what is the output of the command?

Comment: I think I am not clear in my question let me try: so the output is of 2 lines I mentioned above those 2 exports , grepping the id1 and id2 so they can be passed further.

Comment: what do you mean `id1 is cfdsgbds4r4ew43vf`? is `id1` a variable? if not, please update the question to use a common value throughout (as opposed to jumping between different values); what is the exact/complete output from your `robot` call? are you looking for the 'echo' to be part of the ouput?

Comment: @markp-fuso yes I have clarified already that id1 and id2 is indeed a variable , every execution of the robot gives you a different output based on the input. so yes it's a variable and they are being set to VAR1 and VAR2. The output from robot call is just that `export  VAR1=*` and in next line `export VAR2=*` . Hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 0):

If the variables are safe to use and you are sure that the output is safe and will not incidentally format your hard drive and erase all data, you may use `eval` with a process substitution:

```
eval "$(robot ... | grep ...)"
export VAR1="$id1"   # ie. after edit
export VAR2="$id2"
```

just like [`docker-machine env`](https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/env/) or [ssh-agent](https://kb.iu.edu/d/aeww). Be sure to read [eval command and security issues](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048).

A way better, safer way and also requiring more work is to write your own parser for the data, tokenize and extract names and values of variables from the output and assign and export them yourself.

Comment: sorry @kamilCuk I just fixed , it's actually the VAR1 and VAR2 that are id1 and id2 not the actual values. :(